# Silverlight TabControl ContentTemplate

Tags: silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol

I'm struggling to port the following piece of code from WPF to SL:

<

```
TabControl ...
ItemTemplate={StaticResource someResource}>
ContentTemplate={StaticResource someResource2} />
```

Apparently the **TabControl** in SL doesn't contain **ContentTemplate** binding property.

What's the workaround for this issue?
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and found following solution on the web:

http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-data-binding/

Works fine for me in conjunction with Caliburn.Micro Bindings.

Comment: Thanks. It completed the missing piece in a puzzle